# FindWindowA Can't find process

Tags: c++, winapi

I tried to check value from a game but it seems `FindWindowA` can't find this game process I tried with other games and it worked. I checked in Process Hacker how the window is called and it still the same as in code but it still didn't work.

**First project.cpp : main project file.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

DWORD pid;
DWORD Ammo = 0x01E7A938;
int MyAmmo;


int main()
{
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, ("War Thunder Client"));    
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    while (true)
    {
        cout << MyAmmo << endl;
        Sleep(100);
        system("CLS");
    }
        system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: *"I know its the real process name"* - Processes don't have names. This question is unclear, and unanswerable as written. Recommending to close.

Comment: I clearly stated, that I didn't get your point, and I'm somewhat sure that you don't even know specifically, what you need. Plus, inconsistent formatting is the telltale sign of a sloppy thinker. You need to clean up the mess in your head first.

Comment: You don't check for errors when you call these functions. It doesn't look like you read any documentation.

Comment: You probably don't have the necessary privileges to access the process. If you'd checked the error codes, you'd know for sure. This code is a disaster, exhibits all sorts of terrible practices, and isn't even useful, since it hard-codes a window handle that will change every time the window is re-opened.

Comment: Why u post somthing to tell im lazy or somthing, im just looking for help, respect others, i just started c++ so don't get mad...

Comment: @CodyGray I'dont see any hard coded windowh andle here ?

Comment: And its a base adress..

Comment: You can help yourself by reading the documentation and thinking about what you are doing. Copying random bits of code and hoping that they might do something useful isn't constructive. Do you want us to do this for you, or do you want to learn? Remember that this site isn't about your problem. Our goal here is to build Q&A topics that are useful broadly.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should check if `FindWindowA` does actually find your window. If it does not than `hWnd` will have the value of `NULL`.

Second, the value of `MyAmmo` is not set everywhere. It is initalised to `0` because it is a global variable, but otherwise it's value is not changed anywhere.

Comment: how can i check if FindWindowA actually does find window? Thanks for help

Comment: `if (hWnd) { \*window found do something *\ } else { cerr << "Error: window not found!" }`

Comment: OK it does find the window but not the value, wierd

Comment: You are not reading anything into that value. As I said it before the of `MyAmmo` is not changed. You should use something like `ReadProcessMemory`.

Comment: Thanks I tested with other game it reads the value, but when i test it with " War Thunder" it shows 0, what is the problem ?

Comment: Well I can not answer this question. Here you will have to use a debugger to find the problem.

Comment: The code reads nothing, @strane. The address variable, for instance, is not used. I suggest you think a little rather than ask us to do that for you.